How to make slicer with (all, 1, 2, 3+) values
I got one simple slicer whitch takes values from table.
Values can to from 1 to 30.

How to remake slicer to this logic:
all - all values;
1 - select rows with "1" value;
2 - with "2" value;
3+ - select values from 3 to 30.


create a parent table to the source of the slicer table. then add a second slicer to filter it. Same as you would for a table or whatever.

I would create a new column with a SWITCH to generate the ALL, 1, 2, 3+ values based on the Value and have the Slicer use the new column.
